# Selector para clase que empieza por un texto

Tags: css

Tengo unos divs que vienen de una consuta a una base de datos..

```
<div class="comentario1">

</div>
<div class="comentario2">

</div>
<div class="comentario3">

</div>
```

Existo alguna forma de seleccionar todos los elementos que tengan la clase "comentario*" ???

Comment: porque no los nombras todos como comentario? Y ya los puedes seleccionar

Comment: porque luego meto ese comentario* como parámetro de una funcion js

Answer (score 0):

Usando [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) puedes usar la siguiente sintaxis para seleccionar por prefijo, todos los `divs` que en su atributo `class` tengan el prefijo `comentario`.

```js
const $comentarios = document.querySelectorAll('div[class^="comentario"]')

console.log($comentarios)
```

```html
<div class="comentario1">

</div>
<div class="comentario2">

</div>
<div class="comentario3">

</div>
```

Comment: Gracias... Pero como podria usar ese selector mediante JS ?? document.getElementsByClassName() pero cual dentro ??? el mismo ?

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5110337/11193320

### Traduzco una respuesta de Stack Overflow.

Lo que necesitas se llama selector de atributo. Un ejemplo usando tu html:

```
div[class^="tocolor-"],
div[class*=" tocolor-"] { 
    color:red 
}
```

En lugar del div puedes añadir cualquier elemento o borrarlo todo y en lugar de una clase añadir cualquier atributo de un elemento determinado.

`[class^="tocolor-"]` — empieza por "tocolor-".

`[class*=" tocolor-"]` — contiene la subcadena "tocolor-"  directamente después de un espacio.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/K3693/1/

(...)

Espero que la traducción sea correcta y que te sirva.

**Solución**

En tu caso, entiendo, bastaría con `div[class^="comentario"]`. A mí, al menos, me ha funcionado.

Y para capturar los divs como JS:

> var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div[class^='comentario' ]");

Puedes consultar la documentación sobre selectores de atributos en español en [https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_atributo](http://Mozilla%20Developers)